# Android screen AND audio record library

Tags: android, audio-recording, video-recording

I need some way to record android screen AND audio. I have seen some libraries that record screen, but I need audio too. Does such a thing exists? Anybody knows any library to do that? I know something similar is available for iOS (ReplayKit), but seems that is not available for Android. Any alternative for Android?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing in the Android SDK that allows you to record the screen are the media projection APIs. They do not include sound. However, there is nothing stopping you from recording sound yourself and attempting to merge the two. The problem is in getting the audio to accurately sync up with the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking into https://github.com/saki4510t/ScreenRecordingSample.

It  does record the screen's video and audio from the microphone.